# How do I assign an already known integer to a field after the NotInList event is called?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have this complicated VBA function on a MSAccess form `frm_DataEntry`. It searches for values which are not in a list. The function is called on de NotInList event of the comboboxes.

When the typed string in combobox `cbo_CustomerLocations` is not in the list, it will ask if I want to add it to the table `tbl_CustomerLocations` by Yes/No question. After that it goes from 1st column to the last column and asks if I want to add some new data. The code below shows how to add a `CustomerLocation`.

The last field `CustomerID` of my table `tbl_CustomerLocations` is linked to the `CustomerID` field of table `tbl_Customers`

Now my question:

How do I alter my VBA code when the NotInList event is called, and when it reaches the `CustomerID` column (the last column), It must not ask '`What do you want for CustomerID`', but rather automatically selects the CustomerID I previously selected on the same form `frm_DataEntry` on combobox `cbo_Customers`?

```
Private Sub cbo_CustomerLocationID_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)

    Dim oRS As DAO.Recordset, i As Integer, sMsg As String
    Dim oRSClone As DAO.Recordset

    Response = acDataErrContinue
    
    String_Value = Me.cbo_CustomerLocationID.Text
    
    MsgBold = String_Value
    MsgNormal = "Add to list with locations?"
    
    Debug.Print
    
    If Eval("MsgBox ('" & MsgBold & vbNewLine _
    & "@" & MsgNormal & "@@', " & vbYesNo & ", 'New Location')") = vbYes Then
        Set oRS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_CustomerLocations", dbOpenDynaset)
        oRS.AddNew
        oRS.Fields(1) = NewData
        For i = 2 To oRS.Fields.Count - 1
            sMsg = "What do you want for " & oRS(i).Name
            oRS(i).Value = InputBox(sMsg, , oRS(i).DefaultValue)
        Next i
        oRS.Update
        cbo_CustomerLocationID = Null
        cbo_CustomerLocationID.Requery
        DoCmd.OpenTable "tbl_CustomerLocations", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
        Me.cbo_CustomerLocationID.Text = String_Value

End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Rather than using a number of input boxes to get the information that you need, consider creating a small pop-up form to allow the user to add all of the data at once - also it allows you an easy way to do data validation.

Comment: I alreay have a form frm_CustomerEdit where users can link a new location to an existing Customer. I also have small popup-forms for other things like the sort of Material etc. So yes, I can open the form frm_CustomerEdit on the NotInList event but that is not the way I wanted my database to work. Thanks anyway Applecore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an If Then block within the loop to check for name of field.

```
If oRS(i).Name = "CustomerID" Then
    oRS(i) = Me.cbo_Customers
Else
    sMsg = "What do you want for " & oRS(i).Name
    oRS(i).Value = InputBox(sMsg, , oRS(i).DefaultValue)
End If
```